# Create a file of 5 lines consisting of 9 random characters in MacOS Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to create a text file of 5 lines that will consist of 9 random characters of "ATGC"

I ran the following code below, but the text file created has only 1 line.

```
$ for i in $(seq 1 5); do < /dev/urandom LC_CTYPE=C tr -dc "ATGC" | head -c 9 > file.txt; done
```

Could you help?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have an unwanted `;` before `do`. Also, change `>` to `>>`.

Comment: Thanks! That works! Just one more question, how do I get to the next line, after a line of 9 random characters? With your suggestion, it seems to print everything on a single line.

Comment: Just need to know how to include an ‘\n’ after every 9 letters of random characters. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ for i in {1..5}
do
    echo $(LC_ALL=C tr -dc "ATGC" < /dev/urandom | head -c9) >> file.txt
done
```